# Java multiple table query

Tags: java, mysql

I want to do a query with 2 table, but, i cant
this is the code, but doesn't work
any idea?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/kalandpark","root","");
            Statement stmt=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            // int vk=(Integer)jList1.getSelectedValue();
            String vk=vkTF.getText();
            String SQL="Select * from belepes where vonalkod="+vk+" and belepes.jegytipus=jegy.jegytipus";
            stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            jTextField1.enableInputMethods(false);
            while (rs.next())
            {

                int uvk= (int) rs.getDouble("vonalkod");
                String jegyt= rs.getString("jegytipus");
                String belep= rs.getString("belepett");
                String idolejar= rs.getString("idolejar");
                String kilepett= rs.getString("kilepett");
                int ssz= rs.getInt("sorszam");
                int ar = rs.getInt("ar");
                String jegyt2= rs.getString("jegytipus");
                jvonalkoD.setText(""+uvk);
                jJegytipuS.setText(jegyt);        
                jbelepetT.setText(belep);
                jidolejaR.setText(idolejar);
                jkilepetT.setText(kilepett);
                jar.setText(""+ar);

            }
```

Comment: if my guess is correct, you want to combine your TABLE "jegy" and TABLE "belepes" ?

Comment: do similar to : `Select * from belepes b, jegy j where b.vonalkod="+vk+" and b.jegytipus=j.jegytipus`

Comment: If you answer included concatenating parameters into an sql query, your answer is wrong.

Comment: that's a pointer (using his statement) not exactly the ans. let him figure out what suits his requirement & of course how to construct a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, learn [SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/). You seem to lack basic knowledge.

Next, never, **ever**, **EVER** concatenate values into SQL strings in Java, like this:

```
String SQL="Select * from belepes where vonalkod="+vk+" and belepes.jegytipus=jegy.jegytipus";
```

Instead, use the setter methods in PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

You say "two tables" but you've only got one table in your "from" clause.  You need to include a join to the "jegy" table.

Answer (score -1):

if my Guess is Correct Jegy is the other table? in that case try this!

```
String SQL="SELECT * FROM belepes A LEFT JOIN jegy B ON B.jegytipus = A.jegytipus WHERE vonalkod='"+vk+"'";
```

Answer (score -1):

The probleme resolved
this is the correct SQL

String SQL="Select * from belepes b inner join jegy j on b.jegytipus=j.jegytipus where b.vonalkod="+vk;